# What causes btrfs to be loaded at boot-time?

Tags: boot, kernel, btrfs

On my machine, I noticed in dmesg, that it runs benchmarks during boot time:

```
[53263.092443] raid6: avx2x4   gen() 31855 MB/s
[53263.160430] raid6: avx2x4   xor()  9347 MB/s
[53263.228450] raid6: avx2x2   gen() 32426 MB/s
[53263.296449] raid6: avx2x2   xor() 19138 MB/s
[53263.364436] raid6: avx2x1   gen() 29644 MB/s
[53263.432438] raid6: avx2x1   xor() 16857 MB/s
[53263.500440] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 16351 MB/s
[53263.568442] raid6: sse2x4   xor()  8600 MB/s
[53263.636461] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 17461 MB/s
[53263.704464] raid6: sse2x2   xor() 11104 MB/s
[53263.772466] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 14401 MB/s
[53263.840469] raid6: sse2x1   xor() 10014 MB/s
[53263.840470] raid6: using algorithm avx2x2 gen() 32426 MB/s
[53263.840470] raid6: .... xor() 19138 MB/s, rmw enabled
[53263.840471] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[53263.843034] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx
```

So I wonder why my machine was loading raid6 at all. It's not a server, there is no raid in that machine.

It turns out raid6_pq is loaded by btrfs:

```
# lsmod | grep raid6
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
```

But btrfs is not in use at all:

```
# lsmod | grep btrfs
btrfs                1318912  0
xor                    24576  1 btrfs
raid6_pq              114688  1 btrfs
libcrc32c              16384  4 nf_conntrack,nf_nat,btrfs,xfs
```

Would it not be better if btrfs was loaded when required, instead of preemptively? At the very least, it would skip 12 benchmarks during boot.

**OS:** Ubuntu 20.10